# How do i set the image to appear at the end of the timer in another random place?

Tags: java, android, random, timer, libgdx

Im trying to make image reappear at the end of the timer. i cant figure out what i did wrong. the image appears in a random spot in the beginning but thats it.
what i need is for the application to launch and then display the 3 dots in random places and every 1 second appear in another random place

```
public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture blue;
    Texture red;
    Texture green;
    Sprite spriteb;
    Sprite spriter;
    Sprite spriteg;
    int x;
    int y;
    Random random = new Random();
    private float counter;
    private int number;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        blue = new Texture("blue.png");
        red = new Texture("red.png");
        green = new Texture("green.png");
        spriteb = new Sprite(blue);
        spriter = new Sprite(red);
        spriteg = new Sprite(green);
        spriteb.setPosition(random.nextInt(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()), random.nextInt(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));
        spriter.setPosition(random.nextInt(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()), random.nextInt(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));
        spriteg.setPosition(random.nextInt(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()), random.nextInt(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));


    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        spriteb.draw(batch);
        spriter.draw(batch);
        spriteg.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
    }

        public void render (float deltaTime) {
            counter -= deltaTime;
            if (counter <= 0) {
                spriteb.setPosition(random.nextInt(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()), random.nextInt(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));
                counter += 1000; // add one second
                batch.begin();
                spriteb.draw(batch);
                batch.end();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Heres a suggestion... Move 'counter -= deltaTime' out of before the if loop and put it in the if loop as an else clause

Comment: Is the code in the if statement eber finishing?

Comment: no its like the code doesnt do anything. i can delete the whole block and it doesnt has no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't invent a wheel. I think this solution will be good for you:

```
Timer.schedule(
    new Task(){ 
        @Override 
        public void run() {
             spriteb.setPosition(random.nextInt(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()), random.nextInt(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));
             spriter.setPosition(random.nextInt(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()), random.nextInt(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));
             spriteg.setPosition(random.nextInt(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()), random.nextInt(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));
        } 
    }, delay, interval);
```

Put this code into your `create()` method and see if its working. Write if something still not working.

Comment: thank you. that worked great. would i use an array to make the same copys of the images to appear at the end of the timer in random spots?? i want more the one of all the images

Comment: yes i want another sprite r b and g every second. sorry wasnt sure how to say that

Comment: Make 3 libgdx Array<Sprite>, make 3 new sprites, change positions and put there. Than in your render method iterate through these arrays and call sprite.draw

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to be constructive here but I am having a hard time understanding what is being called where.

If I was you I would add in some sort of description on what is being called where, or the full code you wrote.

Now Straight to the point

in your render() method

```
boolean regeneratePosition;
count -= delta; 
if(count<=0) 
count = Time;
regeneratePosition = true;
}
if(regeneratePosition) {
//your regenerate position code goes here
}
```

The other code remain.

Hope this helped